# Stop button where the text stops

Tags: css

I have a little CSS issue right here. I'm creating a simple button and I have the desired effect and all; but the button doesn't stop and acts like `width:100%` while I have width set to `auto`. I have put my code below and the effect is currently has.

[>> CURRENT OUTCOME](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xDefD.png)

```
a.abutton {
    display:block;
    background-color: #49b4df;
    background-image: -webkit-linear-gradient(#49b4df, #2497c5);
    background-image: -moz-linear-gradient(#49b4df, #2497c5);
    background-image: -o-linear-gradient(#49b4df, #2497c5);
    background-image: linear-gradient(#49b4df, #2497c5);
    filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient(startColorStr='#49B4DF', EndColorStr='#2497C5');
    width: auto;
    height: 31px;
    color: #fff;
    font-family: Verdana, Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
    font-size: 12px;
    font-weight: bold;
    margin: 0px 0px 0px 0px;
    padding: 2px 5px 5px 5px;
    border: 0px none;
    border-radius: 3px;
    -webkit-border-radius: 3px;
    -moz-border-radius: 3px;
    -moz-box-shadow: 1px 1px 2px #919191;
    -webkit-box-shadow: 1px 1px 2px #919191;
    box-shadow: 1px 1px 2px #919191;
}
```

Question: How do I stop the button from expanding and stop where the text also stops?

Comment: Try to avoid linking to images. This will attract downvotes, as people will likely not follow your link. All content should be in on place: the question. When you gain enough reputation, you'll be able to add images to posts

Comment: @AlexTartan Yes, I understand but SO is not letting me post images. Issue has been solved, thanks for the feedback.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to change

```
display: block;
```

by

```
display: inline-block;
```

"width:auto" inherit the parent "width" with a "display: block."

Comment: Thank you for the answer, you're awesome.

Answer (score 0):

You need to change the display to inline-block

Comment: Thank you for your input, it worked. :)